# How to use Java's inner anonymous classes in Nativescript-angular?

Tags: java, typescript, nativescript, azure-ad-msal

I would like to implement below Java's implementation in Nativescript-angular where it uses interface implementation using anonymous class concept.

I have followed the below link.
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface

Java code:

```
import com.microsoft.identity.client.IPublicClientApplication;

public class SingleAccountModeFragment extends Fragment {

private ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication mSingleAccountApp;

public void initialize()
{
    PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(getContext(),
                R.raw.auth_config_single_account,
                new IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreated(ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication application) {
                        mSingleAccountApp = application;
                        loadAccount();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                        displayError(exception);
                    }
                });
}
private void loadAccount() { 
    //some code  
}
}
```

Typescript code:

```
export class LoginService{
    mSingleAccountApp;
    res = utils.ad.resources.getId(":raw/auth_config");
    context = applicationModule.android.context;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor created");
        console.log("value of res is: ", this.res);
        const test = global.com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(this.context,this.res,      
                new global.com.microsoft.identity.client.IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener( 
                {
                    constructor() {},
                    onCreated: function(application) {
                        this.mSingleAccountApp = application;
                        this.loadAccount();
                    },
                    onError: function(exception) {
                        //displayError(exception);
                    }
                }));
    }

    loadAccount(): void {
        console.log("Account is loaded");
    }
```

I am not able to use "mSingleAccountApp" outside the interface implementation (Anonymous class) in TypeScript. It gives me error as undefined. If I access the variable "mSingleAccountApp" inside interface implementation then it is defined.

I am also not able to call loadAccount() function of LoginService service. Seems like "this" pointer is  pointing to the interface implementation (Anonymous class) and not to the LoginService class

In JAVA code, both the things are possible and I would like to achieve similar in TypeScript.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Java and TypeScript/JavaScript have nothing to do with one another. Why should the concepts in one language apply to the other?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am aware about it. But I would like to call Java library functions from Typescript. The Java code has been added for sample purpose.